How can I make my .bib file to be correctly compiled into .pdf-file using Angewandte style with biblatex, biber and a main.tex using inputenc?
My .bib-file is not compiled correctly into .pdf-file. Does anyone know how to fix that?
Linked crowded question of the whole project see Migration of thesis written in \documentclass{DissOnlineLatex} to \documentclass [12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew, backend=biber, articletitle=true, chaptertitle=true]{biblatex}
\title{Quellenverzeichnis}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{Literatur.bib}
@article{bre09,
    author  = {J.L. Br\'edas , J. E. Norton, J. Cornil, V. Coropceanu, A. O\'Connor},
    title   = {Molecular Understanding of Organic Solar Cells: The Challenges},
    journal = {Accounts of Chemical Research},
    volume  = {42},
    year    = {2009},
    pages   = {1691},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{bre09}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatur.bib}
\clearpage
\end{document}


have you run latex then biber then latex twice more? what error did you get?

you have \cite{bre} but your bibliography has no entry with that key so you will get an error and no bibliography entry.  you need \cite{bre09}

My fault just corrected.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Use 'and' instead of ',' in your author ...

you should show any errors that you get, running biber on that I get WARN - Entry with key 'bre09' in section '0' is cited and found but not created (likely due to sourcemap) INFO - WARNINGS: 1 INFO - ERRORS: 1

Last Comma was to much, as well as the Commas in the author-section which have to be replaced by "and". So both parts of the failure are the same.

On your example biber gives a slightly obscure error due to the incorrect use of commas in the author list, and some clear warnings about extra commas that should be removed,
using
@article{bre09,
    author  = {J.L. Br\'edas and J. E. Norton and J. Cornil and V. Coropceanu},
    title   = {Molecular Understanding of Organic Solar Cells: The Challenges},
    journal = {Accounts of Chemical Research},
    volume  = {42},
    year    = {2009},
    pages   = {1691}
 }

and runnng pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex  produces


with the modified example in the question
biber gives the warning
ERROR - Name "J.L. Brédas , J. E. Norton, J. Cornil, V. Coropceanu, A. OĆonnor"
 has too many commas, skipping entry 'bre09'

note this is taken as a single name with too many (more than one) commas and \O'C puts an accute accent on C.
replacing the comma by and
author  = {J.L. Br\'edas and  J. E. Norton and J. Cornil and 
          V. Coropceanu and  A. O\'Connor},

biber runs with no error and running pdflatex twice more produces

So replacing the acute accent by an apostrophe:
author  = {J.L. Br\'edas and  J. E. Norton and J. Cornil and
           V. Coropceanu and  A. O'Connor},

and repeating pdflatex,biber,pdflatex, pdflatex produces the expected:


@Teepeemm oops I missed a comma, will fix, thanks

@Teepeemm fixed

Next Failure is after compiling main.tex with input of Literatur.tex C:\Users\asus\OneDrive\Dokumente\Zusammenschrift_Diss_de_V02.09.13>biber main.tex
INFO - This is Biber 2.20
INFO - Logfile is 'main.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'main.tex.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

@PeterZilkens biber main not biber main.tex (biber never reads the tex file)

@PeterZilkens In your question, you specified biber as backend. Why do you compile with bibtex?

@samcarter: I am open for changes. Biblatex just came with the original documentclass.

ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_bWqR\fe6d16e8a0935a16f008a64fa11444f8_23956.utf8, line 773, syntax error: found "year", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_bWqR\fe6d16e8a0935a16f008a64fa11444f8_23956.utf8, line 4, warning: 15 characters of junk seen at toplevel

did you really get that error (looking like a missing } on line 773 from the document that you posted here? Giving error messages from documents you have not shown doesn't help much. @PeterZilkens

Now looking for the missing bracket. @David: Should I really post the whole Literatur.bib here?

No but you should post an example of the problem . Posting code that does not give the error you are asking about is just a waste of everyone's time.  you can start with a copy of your document, delete all the document text apart from \cite{*}  then delete any bib entries you can delete while still showing the error. Probably you will find the problem yourself, but if not, post a small complete example here for someone to debug.

There was a comma in line 770 missing. Nevertheless the compiler complies on \cite{bre09}. the general code is found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732472/migration-of-thesis-written-in-documentclassdissonlinelatex-to-documentclass

The following string stops the whole .bib-file-compilation: O' in the author name O'Connor. Good to know. ;-). Compilation works now.

\' is the command for an acute accent, why would you have that in O'Connor ? @PeterZilkens

@David: By accident while reviewing and correcting other accents. I had this 2 times in my .bib-file.

Many thx everybody for their discussion and help. Now the .pdf-output looks like it should-- after a one week struggle ;-)

I don't understand but no matter. Glad you got it fixed, I assume this post can now be considered done. @PeterZilkens Next time please try to make any example in your question actually show your problem:-)

@david: Indeed. There was just no space here to present all the written 12 MB with a hundred refrences here.

@PeterZilkens there is never a need to post a file with hundreds of references here. But posting code unrelated to your problem does not help, you could easily have generated a small 1-citation document with a small one-item bibliography that showed your issue and included that in your question.

Now it is related. The answer is supposed to be edited as well, so that any reader might able to follow.

@PeterZilkens I updated the answer. As expected, you get no error from O\'Connor simply get a C-acute in the output.
